# How does Gunzerker perform a melee attack? Which controls for xbox 360?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am playing as Gunzerker on Borderlands II. I need to collect Bullymong hair for the Bad Hair Day level and it requires I finish off a Bullymong with a melee attack. How does Gunzerker perform a melee attack? I am using Xbox 360. Which controls do I use?

Comment: Is it not with r3 ? (by pressing you right analogue joystick) like for the others characters.

Comment: I would assume just disable the gunzerk feat for this mission. A respec to remove it should be no more than $20000 tops.

Comment: Do you know how to do melee attacks with other characters? Is it not working with this one?

Answer (score 3):

You can melee with the Gunzerker the same way you can with any other character.

The default button for melee on Xbox should be the **Right Stick Button**.

If that does not work you should check the Options too see the button layout.